# Different interval for HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

How can i have two different intervals on x-axis in HighCharts? That is in the begining of the x axis the interval between number on x- axis is 100 and later after 5 intervals the interval has to be increased to 500.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in your question, your best bet would be to manually set the xAxis [`tickPositions`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions) like this:

```
xAxis: {
  tickPositions: [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/sfwwbsqu/